# can't generate DB from model code in entity framework

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am learning EF.I have some classes of model and class that inherited from DbContext.
I have intializer `Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` with empty method
Seed.I call

```
 Database.SetInitializer<...Context>(new ...Initializer());
```

And I have set new add to connection strings

```
<add name="...Context" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Temp.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

but I can't generate DB from this.App Data is empty.
Please help me!Probably I forgot something?My method Seed I have left is empty but I don't think it's a trouble
Thank u!

Comment: but I tried to design model of DB by tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a initializer is not enough. You need at least start a query.

In the moment you try to get data from your context, the process will start and if your database
does not exists the will get created.

```
MyDbContext myDbContext = new MyDbContext();
var firstItemOfSomething = myDbContext.FirstItemOfSomething.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi!Thanks.It helps.Actually if u know can I watch all design of this generated DB in visual studio?

Comment: Yes you can open the Server Explorer and connect to your Database. If it was helpful, consider to accept my answer. But only if it was helpful.